# Bibliography file not accepted in Texstudio

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I have typed my references in separate Bibliography file. But when I am running my `.tex` file using TeXstudio, the references are not appearing and it showing an error `Something's wrong-perhaps missing \item. \end{thebibliography}`. Can anybody help me?

I am attaching my bibliography file here for reference. All suggested  method are tried but result is same.

```
@Article{Wren,
   author = " Wren C. and Azarbayejani A.",
   title =   {Pfinder: real-time tracking of the human body},
   journal =   {IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
   number = {7},
   year =   {1997},
   volume =   {19},
   pages =   {780-785},
}
@InProceedings{Kim,
   author =   "Kim H., Sakamoto R., Kitahara I., Toriyama T. and Kogure K. ",
   title =   {Robust foreground extraction technique using Gaussian family model and multiple thresholds},
   booktitle =   {Asian Conference on Computer Vision, ACC 2007},
   OPTpages = {758-768},
year = {2007},
OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Stauffer,
author = "Stauffer C., Grimson E. ",
title = {Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking}, 
booktitle = {IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR},
OPTpages = {246-252},
year = {1999},
}
@InProceedings{Elgammal,
author = " Elgammal, Ahmed, David Harwood, and Larry Davis",
title = {Non-parametric model for background subtraction}, 
booktitle = {Computer Vision ECCV 2000},
OPTpages = {751-767},
year = {2000},
}
@InProceedings{Mittal,
author = "Mittal, Anurag, and Nikos Paragios",
title = {Motion-based background subtraction using adaptive kernel density estimation }, 
booktitle = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR 2004},
% OPTpages = {704-711},
year = {2004},
OPTvolume = {2},
%OPTmonth = {June},
}
@Article{K,
   author =   "Kim K., Chalidabhongswe T.H, Harwood D.",
   title =   {Real-time foreground-background segmentation using codebook model},
   journal =   {Real  Time Imaging},
   number = {3},
   year =   {2005},
   volume =   {11},
   pages =   {172-185},
}
@InProceedings {Doshi,
author = " A. Doshi, M. Trivedi ",
title = {Hybrid cone-cylinder codebook model for foreground detection with shadow and highlight suppression}, 
booktitle = {Video and Signal Based Surveillance,AVSS '06},
%OPTpages = {764-771},
year = {2006},
OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Hu,
   author =   " H. Hu, L. Xu, H. Zhao",
   title =   {A spherical codebook in YUV color space for moving object detection},
   journal =   {Sensor Lett.},
   number = {1},
   year =   {2012},
   volume =   {10},
   pages =   {177-189},
}
@InProceedings{Sigari,
author = " Sigari, Mohamad Hoseyn, and Mahmood Fathy",
title = {Real-time background modeling/subtraction using two-layer codebook model}, 
booktitle = {International MultiConference of Engineering and Computer Scientists},
%OPTpages = {764-771},
 volume =   {1},
year = {2008},
%OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Barnich,
   author =   "Barnich, Olivier, and Marc Van Droogenbroeck",
   title =   {Vibe: A universal background subtraction algorithm for video sequences},
   journal =   {IEEE Transaction on Image Processing},
   number = {6},
   year =   {2011},
  volume =   {20},
   pages =   {1709-1724},
}
@InProceedings{Lin,
author = " Geng-Cheng Lin, SSheng-Chih Yang, Chuin-Mu Wang, Che-Fu Lin",
title = {Background Subtraction Based on Codebook Model and Texture Feature}, 
booktitle = {International Symposium on Computer, Consumer and control},
OPTpages = {498-501},
% volume =   {1},
year = {2016},
%OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Badal,
author = " Tapas Badal, Neeta Nain, Mushtaq Ahmed and Vishakha Sharma",
title = {An Adaptive Codebook Model for Change Detection with Dynamic Background}, 
booktitle = {11th International Conference on Signal-Image Technology and Internet-Based Systems },
OPTpages = {110-116},
% volume =   {1},
year = {2015},
%OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Bouwmans,
   author =   "Thierry Bouwmans",
   title =   {Traditional and recent approaches in background modeling for foreground detection: An overview},
   journal =   {COMPUTERSCIENCE REVIEW11},
   %number = {2},
   year =   {2014},
   volume =   {12},
   pages =   {31-66},
}
```

Comment: The bibliography itself runs without problems for me, so probably there is another problem which is not related to the bibliography. Please make an example document where the problem occurs. Start with, e.g.,:

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\nocite{*}\bibliographystyle{plain}\bibliography{yourbibliographyfile}\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you gave us no TeX code showing how you call your bibliography.  I suppose you are using `bibtex` now.

Then you have two main errors in your bib file:

1. multiple authors have to be divided by the keyword `and`, not with a comma
2. You have several `%` in your bib file which are not allowed. I just deleted them.

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have TeX code and bib file together in one MWE) with some pretty printing in the bib file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Wren,
  author  = " Wren C. and Azarbayejani A.",
  title   = {Pfinder: real-time tracking of the human body},
  journal = {IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
  number  = {7},
  year    = {1997},
  volume  = {19},
  pages   = {780-785},
}
@InProceedings{Kim,
  author = "Kim H. and Sakamoto R. and Kitahara I. and Toriyama T. and Kogure K. ",
  title = {Robust foreground extraction technique using Gaussian family model and multiple thresholds},
  booktitle = {Asian Conference on Computer Vision, ACC 2007},
  OPTpages = {758-768},
  year = {2007},
  OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Stauffer,
author = "Stauffer C. and Grimson E. ",
title = {Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking}, 
booktitle = {IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR},
OPTpages = {246-252},
year = {1999},
}
@InProceedings{Elgammal,
author = " Elgammal, Ahmed and David Harwood and Larry Davis",
title = {Non-parametric model for background subtraction}, 
booktitle = {Computer Vision ECCV 2000},
OPTpages = {751-767},
year = {2000},
}
@InProceedings{Mittal,
  author = "Mittal, Anurag and Nikos Paragios",
  title = {Motion-based background subtraction using adaptive kernel density estimation }, 
  booktitle = {Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR 2004},
  OPTpages = {704-711},
  year = {2004},
  OPTvolume = {2},
  OPTmonth = {June},
}
@Article{K,
  author =   "Kim K. and Chalidabhongswe T.H and Harwood D.",
  title =   {Real-time foreground-background segmentation using codebook model},
  journal =   {Real  Time Imaging},
  number = {3},
  year =   {2005},
  volume =   {11},
  pages =   {172-185},
}
@InProceedings {Doshi,
author = " A. Doshi and M. Trivedi ",
title = {Hybrid cone-cylinder codebook model for foreground detection with shadow and highlight suppression}, 
booktitle = {Video and Signal Based Surveillance,AVSS '06},
OPTpages = {764-771},
year = {2006},
OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Hu,
   author =   " H. Hu and L. Xu and H. Zhao",
   title =   {A spherical codebook in YUV color space for moving object detection},
   journal =   {Sensor Lett.},
   number = {1},
   year =   {2012},
   volume =   {10},
   pages =   {177-189},
}
@InProceedings{Sigari,
author = " Sigari, Mohamad Hoseyn and Mahmood Fathy",
title = {Real-time background modeling/subtraction using two-layer codebook model}, 
booktitle = {International MultiConference of Engineering and Computer Scientists},
OPTpages = {764-771},
 volume =   {1},
year = {2008},
OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Barnich,
   author =   "Barnich, Olivier and Marc Van Droogenbroeck",
   title =   {Vibe: A universal background subtraction algorithm for video sequences},
   journal =   {IEEE Transaction on Image Processing},
   number = {6},
   year =   {2011},
  volume =   {20},
   pages =   {1709-1724},
}
@InProceedings{Lin,
  author = "Geng-Cheng Lin and SSheng-Chih Yang and Chuin-Mu Wang and Che-Fu Lin",
  title = {Background Subtraction Based on Codebook Model and Texture Feature}, 
  booktitle = {International Symposium on Computer, Consumer and control},
  OPTpages = {498-501},
  volume =   {1},
  year = {2016},
  OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@InProceedings{Badal,
author = "Tapas Badal and Neeta Nain and Mushtaq Ahmed and Vishakha Sharma",
title = {An Adaptive Codebook Model for Change Detection with Dynamic Background}, 
booktitle = {11th International Conference on Signal-Image Technology and Internet-Based Systems },
OPTpages = {110-116},
 volume =   {1},
year = {2015},
OPTmonth = {Nov.},
}
@Article{Bouwmans,
  author  = "Thierry Bouwmans",
  title   = {Traditional and recent approaches in background modeling 
             for foreground detection: An overview},
  journal = {COMPUTERSCIENCE REVIEW11},
  number  = {2},
  year    = {2014},
  volume  = {12},
  pages   = {31-66},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}  % to test more entries, not cited in document
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{\jobname} % to use bib file created with filecontents
\end{document}
```

I can compile without error or warning (the one warning about `filecontents` is okay) to the following result:

[image]